# Anomalous speed up of F2py with muliprocessing

Tags: python, fortran, multiprocessing, f2py

I have a python front end, and a fortran back end, using F2py to call a python wrapper function "gBulk_kZ" for a fortran function.
I was comparing the time of two methods. The first with multiprocessing, the second just using the map function. Running the multiprocessing over just one processor gives x100 speed up. If I leave the processor choice empty then it runs in about 14.0ms.
Why is multiprocessing so much faster than just map in the case that i'm just using one processor?

Method 1: time = 6.9ms

```
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(1)
g = partial(gBulk_kZ,m,n,s_lat)
glist = pool.map(g,Elist)
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

Method 2: time = 690.4ms

```
g = partial(gBulk_kZ,m,n,s_lat)
glist = map(g,Elist)
```

And then they both write out in the same way.

Comment: What does the Fortran subroutine do?

Comment: The fortran subroutine calculates an integral over a function that is of the form 
(e^(i(f(x) + x)))/(cos(x)sin(f(x)))
where f(x) is a complicated acos function.

Comment: Did you confirm that the results are right in both cases?

Comment: yup. results are identical. tested for a variety of cases.

Answer (score 0):

I can now answer my own question.
I was using time.clock() to measure time.
This does not work for some reason.
time.time() gives the expected answer.
My bad.